# Interface same name as its method parameter type

Tags: java

```
public interface TreeValue {
   public boolean lessThan(TreeValue value)
}
```

Hello everyone,

I came across this example and I have no idea why TreeValue in the 
method has the same name as the interface. Why not int?
What is the advantage of using the same name as the interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that this method `lessThan` is comparing two Tree value objects. This is like the `equals` method of any `Object`

Answer (score 1):

This is no different than an object's `equals` signature...

```
public boolean equals(Integer otherInteger)
```

... or the [implementation of `compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (where `T` is defined as `Long`).

```
public int compareTo(Long otherObject)
```

Here, your interface is defining a method that accepts another class that implements `TreeValue`, and allowing you to do an operation on it.  Here, it's allowing you to compare two `TreeValue`-like classes together to produce a boolean result.

The key here is context.  Regardless of how the method is actually implemented, the intention here is that the interface is acting on another class which implements it, thus keeping the context of the the operation clear.

Comment: I understand but why is the type of the parameter TreeValue (same name as the interface) and not an integer ? Is there an advantage of using TreeValue as the type and not an integer ?

Comment: Yes.  It basically gives your code context into what it needs to operate with.  It's not trying to do a `lessThan` operation on an `Integer`, it's trying to do it with respect to an instance of (something that implements) `TreeValue`.